# Initailize Sender of GCM (Google Cloud Message) issue

Tags: java, android, google-cloud-messaging

I would like to send a message to an Android mobile with GCM (Google Cloud Message). 
But when the process goes to 
`Sender sender = new Sender(serverKey);`

the process stopped but there is no exception thrown. It seems that issue happends when create an instance of Sender, but it does not throw any exception outside.

How can I get the exception information? The serverKey is correct. Why this sentence has error?

```
@Override
public void sendMessage(String msg) {
    try {
        String serverKey = "aaaa";
        String regId = "xxxxxx";
        Sender sender = new Sender(serverKey);
        Message message = new Message.Builder().addData("msg", msg).build();
        Result result = sender.send(message, regId, 5);
        String status = "Sent message to one device: " + result;
        System.out.println(status);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `Sender` class has only one constructor, and here is its code:

```
  public Sender(String key) {
    this.key = nonNull(key);
  }
```

The only way this constructor can throw an exception is if you pass it a `null` key (which will result in `IllegalArgumentException`).

Therefore, either you are passing `null` to that constructor or you are not getting any exception in that line.

Actually, another option is that your process has no access to `gcm-server.jar`, which contains the `Sender` class.

Comment: What is the reason that the process has no access to gcm-server.jar? I have put this jar into /WebContent/WEB-INF/lib, and add it into the build path of the project.